# Troubleshooting Play Framework Installation / Execution

Tags: java, playframework, debian

Working on installing the Java "Play" framework (2.2.5) on Debian... seem to have everything installed properly but the file won't run even after modding it with +x:

```
myuser@Home:~/play-2.2.5$ ls -la
total 44
drwxrwxr-x  5 root    root    4096 Oct  6 20:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 31 myuser  myuser  4096 Oct 21 13:24 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    root    8700 Oct  6 20:57 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxr-x  9 root    root    4096 Oct  6 20:57 framework
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root    root    1795 Oct  6 20:57 play
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    root    1453 Oct  6 20:57 play.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    root    1872 Oct  6 20:57 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 root    root    4096 Oct  6 20:57 repository
drwxrwxr-x  4 root    root    4096 Oct  6 20:57 samples
myuser@Home:~/play-2.2.5$ play
bash: play: command not found
```

Java is installed..

```
myuser@Home:~/play-2.2.5$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

How should I troubleshoot from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the path in Linux does not include the current directory. If you want to run an executable not in the path, you need to specify the full path to the file. For the current directory, specifying the directory `.` will do the job.

```
myuser@Home:~/play-2.2.5$ ./play
                          ^^
```